# In HighCharts, how can I make the color for each plotted point in an array dependent on a value in a corresponding array?

Tags: arrays, plot, highcharts, colors, point

For example say the array I would like to graph is [3,4,6,4,2,1,2] and the corresponding color array is [1,2,1,3,2,2,2] where 1=red,2=blue,3=green etc. I could change the array to ['red','blue','red' ...] if that helps.

Is there any way to get the points to display with the proper color using an array?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the points as arrays or objects and associate a correct color with the point.

The use of an array and the [series.keys](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.keys) property:

```
series: [{
        type: 'scatter',
        keys: ['y', 'color'],
        data: [[3, 'red'],[4, 'blue'],[6, 'red'], [4, 'green'],[2, 'blue'],[1, 'blue'],[2, 'blue']]
    }],
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/8u3q6omm/

Objects:

```
 series: [{
        type: 'scatter',
        data: [{y: 3, color: 'red'},{y: 4, color: 'blue'},{y: 6, color: 'red'}, {y: 4, color: 'green'},{y: 2, color: 'blue'},{y: 1, color: 'blue'},{y: 2, color: 'blue'}]
    }],
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/8u3q6omm/1/

If you have any pattern for the values and the color, you can write a function for associating the color or use Highcharts [zones](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.zones).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!